# Specific gravity of H2O2 bleached viscose

Tags: everyday-chemistry, density

What is the specific gravity of $\ce{H2O2}$ bleached viscose? In literature, I can find that this is $1.52~\mathrm{g~cm^{-3}}$, but for bleached viscose is it not findable. Can I presume $\ce{H2O2}$ treated viscose has the same density?

Answer (score 3):

You can assume that the density remains unchanged.

Hydrogen peroxide simply oxidizes dyes, thereby destroying chromophores (groups that move the absorption of a molecule into the visible spectrum). The viscose structure should remain largely unscathed, and the change in density is so minuscule I would argue it is within the experimental error.